Which one is the latest release polkadot-v1.12.0 or release-polkadot-v1.12.0 or release-crates-io-v1.12.0?
I want to upgrade my chain to latest polkadot version. When I checked the Polkadot-SDK repo. I found two branches: release-polkadot-v1.12.0 and polkadot-v1.12.0.
When I compare both branches, release-polkadot-v1.12.0 is 4 commits ahead of polkadot-v1.12.0.

Can someone please guide me which one is right branch to consider for 1.12.0? What is the difference between these two branches?

crates-io-* is for crates.io.
polkadot-* is a tag for release.
release-* is a branch. It corresponds to that version and may include minor updates.
For me, I always use release-*.

Thank you so much for your answer, It's really helpful.
